# How to solve "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: response.body.forEach is not a function" ? (vue.js 2)

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

My component vue.js is like this :

```
<script>
  export default{
    name: 'CategoryBsSelect',

    template: '\
      <select class="form-control" v-model="selected" required>\
        <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.id" v-bind:disabled="option.disabled">{{ option.name }}</option>\
      </select>',

    //props: {list: {type: String, default: ''}},

    mounted() {
        this.fetchList();
    },

    data() {
      return {
        selected: '',
        options: [{id: '', name: 'Select Category'}]
      };
    },

    methods: {
        fetchList: function() {
            this.$http.post(window.BaseUrl+'/member/category/list').then(function (response) {
                //this.$set('list', response.data);
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response.body))
                response.body.forEach(function(item){
                    this.$set(this.options, item.id, item);
                }, this);
            });
        },
    }

  };

</script>
```

The result of `console.log(JSON.stringify(response.body))` :

> {"20":"Category 1","21":"Category 2","22":"Category 3"}

I want display the response on the value of select. But when executed, on the console exist error like this :

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: response.body.forEach is not a
>   function
>       at VueComponent.

Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: objects don't have a `forEach` - use `Object.keys`

Comment: What do you expect `item` and `item.id` to be?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Object.keys(response.body).map(function(key) {
    this.$set(this.options, key, response.body[key]);
});
```

Comment: Why `map`? Your function isn't returning anything.

Comment: Why not a simple `for` loop?